# primeng tree, p-tree default expanded and selected node with highlighting not working

Tags: angular, primeng

I am using primeng p-tree control with angular 7 application.On running application tree control looks like below:

[image]

As you can see in the above image I am able to achieve the below functionality:

Expanding the node which is default selected(in above case first nodes first child)

I also want to achieve the one more requirement as below:
Default selected node(leaf node) should be highlighted.

I am unable to achieve above requirement.

**Below is the stackblitz URL where you can see the code I am using.**

[stackblitz URL](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-primeng-tree-sml-cfsx3x?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In template  `[(selection)]="node"` set to the node you want to be selected by default.
in component    `this.node =this.filesTree2[0].children[0];`
if you need deeper selection just  `this.node =this.filesTree2[0].children[0].children[0];`

See updated your example 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-primeng-tree-sml-9jgnhw

Comment: yes it is working, It was my mistake, I was using array for selected items with selectionMode="single"